Change state of const in component from another component
I have a react app where I built a simple menu that changes state on click to open and close it. This works fine with the menu button that is in the same component. However I now want to be able to open the menu from another component, in this case from the start page hero.
I have two components: header.js and hero.js
What I'm trying to do is to open the menu when I press the button on the hero.
I tried to import the component, the action, and the state but nothing works. I know I'm doing it wrong but I don't know how to solve it and could not find any solution to it though I'm sure there is one.
Here is my code example.
header.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const menuToggle = event => {
    setIsOpen(current => !current);
  };

  return (
    <header className={`header ${isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}`}>
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </header>
  );
}

hero.js
import setIsOpen from '../header/Header';

export default function Hero() {
  const menuToggle = event => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <section className="hero">
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </section>
  );
}


Does this answer your question? Change component state from another component

I don't understand how to adapt the answer for that issue into the context of mine. Should I have a "global" component with the state that I then import into both header.js and hero.js?

Use the context to share that state

The solution is to lift the isOpen state up to a common ancestor component and pass the state and updaters/callbacks down as props to the appropriate components.
Basic Trivial Example:
Header
export default function Header({ isOpen, menuToggle }) {
  return (
    <header className={["header", isOpen ? "open" : "closed"].join(" ")}>
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </header>
  );
}

Hero
export default function Hero({ menuToggle }) {
  return (
    <section className="hero">
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </section>
  );
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const menuToggle = event => {
    setIsOpen(open => !open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header isOpen={isOpen} menuToggle={menuToggle} />
      <Hero menuToggle={menuToggle} />
    </>
  );
};

If there isn't a direct parent-child relationship between these components then you can either pass the props through all intermediate components until you get to both Header and Hero, or you can implement a React Context to provide the value and avoid the props drilling issue.
Example:
export const MenuContext = React.createContext({
  isOpen: false,
  menuToggle: () => {},
});

export const useMenuContext = () => React.useContext(MenuContext);

const MenuContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const menuToggle = event => {
    setIsOpen(open => !open);
  };

  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider value={{ isOpen, menuToggle }}>
      {children}
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MenuContextProvider;

Render MenuContextProvider as the common ancestor component, and downstream use the useMenuContext to access the context value, wherever the components are.
App
const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <MenuContextProvider>
      ... 
      ... Header somewhere down the ReactTree ...
      ... Hero somewhere down the ReactTree ...
      ...
    </MenuContextProvider>
  );
};

Header
export default function Header() {
  const { isOpen, menuToggle } = useMenuContext();

  return (
    <header className={["header", isOpen ? "open" : "closed"].join(" ")}>
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </header>
  );
}

Hero
export default function Hero() {
  const { menuToggle } = useMenuContext();

  return (
    <section className="hero">
      <button onClick={menuToggle}>Toggle menu</button>
    </section>
  );
}

For more details see:

Sharing State between Components
Passing Data Deeply with Context

